# AddMinutes work but not AddHours?

Tags: c#, android, datetime, xamarin, datepicker

I have a DatePicker and a TimePicker to get the time and date of an evenement.
I manage to get the values from the pickers and want to store them all in a DateTime.
To add the time to the DateTime I use AddMinutes() and AddHours, the AddMinutes works perfectly but not the AddHours even though they are used the exact same way.
What did I do wrong?
Here is where I declare my pickers (the getters work fine)

```
DatePicker dps = FindViewById<DatePicker>(Resource.Id.Start_dp);
DatePicker dpe = FindViewById<DatePicker>(Resource.Id.End_dp);
TimePicker tps = FindViewById<TimePicker>(Resource.Id.Start_tp);
TimePicker tpe = FindViewById<TimePicker>(Resource.Id.End_tp);

dps.UpdateDate(_event.Start_date.Year, _event.Start_date.Month, _event.Start_date.Day);
dpe.UpdateDate(_event.End_date.Year, _event.End_date.Month, _event.End_date.Day);
tps.Hour = _event.Start_date.Hour;
tps.Minute = _event.Start_date.Minute;
tpe.Hour = _event.End_date.Hour;
tpe.Minute = _event.End_date.Minute;`
```

And the update event, where the AddHours doesn't update the DateTime (I verified that the tpe.Hour has a real value other than 0)

```
        Button update_event = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.update_event);

        update_event.Click += delegate
        {
            DateTime dts;
            dts = dps.DateTime.AddHours(tps.Hour);
            dts = dps.DateTime.AddMinutes(tps.Minute);
            DateTime dte;
            dte = dpe.DateTime.AddHours(tpe.Hour);
            dte = dpe.DateTime.AddMinutes(tpe.Minute);


            _event.Name = lieuTitle.Text;
            _event.Start_date = dts;
            _event.End_date = dte;

            Linker.Put<Event>(_event, _event.Id);
        };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should keep on modifing `dts` and `dte`:

```
        DateTime dts;
        dts = dps.DateTime.AddHours(tps.Hour);
        dts = dts.AddMinutes(tps.Minute); // dts

        DateTime dte;
        dte = dpe.DateTime.AddHours(tpe.Hour);
        dte = dte.AddMinutes(tpe.Minute); // dte
```

Or create required value in *one go* which looks *more readable*:

```
         DateTime dts = dps.DateTime
           .AddHours(tps.Hour)
           .AddMinutes(tps.Minute);

         DateTime dte = dpe.DateTime
           .AddHours(tpe.Hour);
           .AddMinutes(tpe.Minute);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, `DateTime` is immutable. When you use `AddHours` or `AddMinutes`, etc. it returns a new `DateTime` object.

So let's say we have code like this:

```
DateTime a, b;
a = DateTime.Now;
b = a.AddHours(1);
b = a.AddMinutes(1);
```

What's going to happen?

1. It's going to assign the `DateTime` object created by `a.AddHours(1)` to `b`. `a` will be unchanged.
2. Next, it's going to assign the `DateTime` object created by `a.AddMinutes(1)` to `b`. `a` will be unchanged.

What do you need to do to fix this? You need to use the new `DateTime` resulting from `AddHours(1)` when you call `AddMinutes(1)`:

```
DateTime a, b;
a = DateTime.Now;
b = a.AddHours(1);
b = b.AddMinutes(1);
```

Or you can just chain it:

```
DateTime a, b;
a = DateTime.Now;
b = a.AddHours(1).AddMinutes(1);
```